# in nodejs request.body is undefined

Tags: node.js, http-post

when i send a post request from my angularjs to nodejs
request.body is undefined, however i m able to receive values when sent through get method

my angularjs code

```
app.controller('create_company', function($scope,$http) {
$scope.save = function() {
    console.log($scope.company);
var temp=$scope.company;
        $http({
            url: "http://localhost:4000/comp/signUp",
            method: "POST",
            data: temp
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.data = data;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.status = status;
        });

    }
```

my nodejs code:

```
var express = require('express');
      var compRouter = express.Router();
      var router = function () {
        compRouter.route('/signUp')
            .post(function (request, response) {
              console.log(request.body);


            });


        return compRouter;
  }
```

Comment: you have to use `body-parse` or other libs to be able to use req.body. Or you can do it yourself. google it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use body-parsing middleware. You can check; https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser